Is there a granted minimum known size of the whole universe? (including the non observable part)
This Forbes article How Much Of The Unobservable Universe Will We Someday Be Able To See?
claims

The unobservable Universe, on the other hand, must be at least 23
trillion light years in diameter

Is this so?
Is there a granted minimum known size of the whole universe? (including the non observable part)

You can find the size of the observable universe and the minimum size of the entire universe, according to the results obtained by the Planck Collaboration in the thread: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/54658/31201 . Regards

@albert so if I got it right, the diameter would be around 19 times larger than the observable universe? Which is nothing like Forbes claims?

Di Valentino+ 19 found from the Planck data alone(i.e. ignoring BAOs, SNe, etc.) a rather high curvature, implying a rather small "whole" Universe only ~3 times larger than the observable, as discussed in this answer.

Does this answer your question? Based off of the study that found the universe has a positive curvature, how big would the whole universe be?

@profrob based on the comments here the answer to my question seems to be "no, there are different estimates to how large the minimum size the whole universe is" . But may be someone who knows more can say some of those estimates are invalid and only one is valid

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/31793/are-there-ways-to-estimate-size-of-the-whole-universe
