The latest news of measuring the size of the universe
I looked through some other materials and gave the answer that the size of the whole universe is about 250 times that of the observable universe, but that was a long time ago. I wonder if the latest data is different.

I voted down because this question is not useful in the context of StackExchange sites.   We would be snowed under by people wanting to ask question like "what is the latest..." and there would be no end of them.  Finding things like that out is what search engines are for,

"I looked through some other materials" what materials?

And https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/31793/are-there-ways-to-estimate-size-of-the-whole-universe
